# oracle sql clarification to use case condition in where clause, error sdo_nn cannot be evaluated without an index

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 11g with oracle spatial, this query works if I use distance as below in the where condition

```
mdsys.sdo_nn ( b1.location, l_location , 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=100 distance='|| 
c1.tier_radius||' unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

however I want the distance evaluated based on condition. Below query gives error sdo_nn cannot be evaluated without an index, I want distance to be evaluated based on condition something like this

```
select
        /*+ first_rows LEADING(c) USE_NL(c1 b1) INDEX(b1 BRANCH_LOCATION_SPIX)*/
        b1.BRANCH_ID,
        mdsys.sdo_nn_distance(1) branchDistance
      from
        branch b1, city c1
      where
        mdsys.sdo_nn ( b1.location, l_location , 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=100 distance='|| (case  when b1.restaurant_id not in (3970,3971,3972) then c1.tier_radius
        else 15 end) ||' unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'   
        and b1.city_id = c1.city_id
```

Comment: Does the query work with this?  `mdsys.sdo_nn ( b1.location, l_location , 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=100 distance=15 unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'`?

Answer (score 0):

We know that the part

```
mdsys.sdo_nn ( b1.location, l_location , 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=100 distance='|| 
c1.tier_radius||' unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

works, then I think you can use such a query containing `union all` as below :

```
select  /*+ first_rows LEADING(c) USE_NL(c1 b1) INDEX(b1 BRANCH_LOCATION_SPIX)*/
        b1.BRANCH_ID,
        mdsys.sdo_nn_distance(1) branchDistance
  from branch b1 
  join city c1 on c1.city_id = b1.city_id
 where mdsys.sdo_nn ( b1.location, l_location , 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=100 distance='||c1.tier_radius||' unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'
   and b1.restaurant_id not in (3970,3971,3972)
union all
select  /*+ first_rows LEADING(c) USE_NL(c1 b1) INDEX(b1 BRANCH_LOCATION_SPIX)*/
        b1.BRANCH_ID,
        mdsys.sdo_nn_distance(1) branchDistance
  from branch b1 
  join city c1 on c1.city_id = b1.city_id
 where mdsys.sdo_nn ( b1.location, l_location , 'SDO_BATCH_SIZE=100 distance=15 unit=KM', 1) = 'TRUE'
   and b1.restaurant_id in (3970,3971,3972)
```

Comment: yes union all works, but won't there be performance issues as with union two queries are being executed instead of one ?

Comment: @Ayub I never met any performance issues related to `union all` (but `union` may cause performance issues ).

Comment: I feel it some what related to the issue mentioned here in one of the examples mentioning the error SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index

 https://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/73/using-oracles-sdonn-operator-some-examples